# Capturing quantifiers

Tags: regex, capture

I have a regex pattern to capture three group:

```
(([abc])([abc])([abc]))
```

How can I rewrite this in the other way?

I tried:

```
(([abc]){1,3})
```

But only the last group was captured.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it only capture the last group (https://regex101.com/r/kX8aB7/1)

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/kX8aB7/2

Comment: use: (([abc])([abc])([abc])), capture each of group 
MATCH 1
1. [0-3] `abc`
2. [0-1] `a`
3. [1-2] `b`
4. [2-3] `c`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this differently unless you use certain regex-engines (I believe .net supports it). If you repeat a capture-group, a repeated match will override the earlier found match of that capture-group. That's why you end up with only the last match.

This is of course a limitation if you don't know how many instances of a sub-pattern are gonna appear but you want to capture each individual match of the sub-pattern in a capture group.

One way around this, depending on the (programming) environment, is to match the repeated pattern as 1 bigger capture group and then run a new regex on the found capture. Example:

```js
var inp = 'some string that matches regex & ac but we don\'t know how many letters after the regex';

var m = inp.match(/(regex).*?([abc]{1,3})/);
          
document.getElementById('out').value=m[2].match(/[abc]/g).join('\n');
```

```html
<textarea id="out" rows="5" style="width:100%"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got your point, you want to capture groups of "abc" as a whole bloc. For example, `abcabcabc` and not `abcabbc`.
If it's the case, then you should use `(abc){1,3}`. See https://regex101.com/r/kX8aB7/3